# tuple of vectors from std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

I'm trying to create a tuple of vectors from a std::tuple (Reason: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) and came up with the following piece of code.

Can anyone think of a more elegant, less verbose solution? PS: I'm stuck with a C++14 compiler...

```
template<std::size_t N, class T, template<class> class Allocator>
struct tuple_of_vectors {};

template<class T, template<class> class Allocator>
struct tuple_of_vectors<1, T, Allocator>
{
    using type = std::tuple
    <
        std::vector
        <
            typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type
                , Allocator<typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type>
        >
    >;
};

template<class T, template<class> class Allocator>
struct tuple_of_vectors<2, T, Allocator>
{
    using type = std::tuple
    <
        std::vector
        <
            typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type
                , Allocator<typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type>
        >,
        std::vector
        <
            typename std::tuple_element<1, T>::type
                , Allocator<typename std::tuple_element<1, T>::type>
        >
    >;
};

// and so on...

template<class T, template<class> class Allocator>
class series
{
public:
    using tov_type = typename tuple_of_vectors
            <std::tuple_size<T>{}, T, Allocator>::type;
        
    tov_type tov_;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don’t think that’s right  — OP isn’t asking us to review the code, he’s asking how to solve a concrete issue with the current code; namely, that the `tuple_of_vectors` specialisations have to be written manually. They should be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C++14 [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to extract the elements of the `tuple`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<class IndexSeq, class Tuple, template<class> class Alloc>
struct tuple_of_vectors;

template<class Tuple, template<class> class Alloc, std::size_t... Is>
struct tuple_of_vectors<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple, Alloc> {
  using type = std::tuple<
    std::vector<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>, 
    Alloc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>>...
  >;
};

template<class Tuple, template<class> class Alloc>
class series {
 public:
  using tov_type = typename tuple_of_vectors<
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>, Tuple, Alloc>::type;
  tov_type tov_;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/h51dTdvoa)

Answer (score 0):

Class template specialisation and pattern matching can help reduce the code size. I include a `static_assert` test below:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct tuple_of_vectors;

template <typename... Ts>
struct tuple_of_vectors<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
};

using t = typename tuple_of_vectors<std::tuple<int,double,float*>>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<t,std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<float*>>>::value,"");
```